# How do I extract data/results from a cURL command to display the output with PHP?

Tags: php, post, curl, get

First off, iam quite new with both PHP and cURL

From the command:

```
curl -i 'http://xxx:xxx/v2.0/tokens' -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"auth": {"tenantName": "xxx", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "admin", "password": "xxx"}}}'
```

I want to produce the results of this command using POST/GET and PHP. I have an apache server and working url.

I just dont know how to make a working code that takes the code and produce the output to an empty page using PHP.

I have been searching examples and I know you got to make use of some of the following:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I just dont know how to attach the proper flags from the cURL command to the PHP code, probably missing a few vital things aswell to wrap the code up.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I could not explain the my problem good enough.

**** ***EDIT:*** ****

So I made a code, that works for my needs, it produces a raw result from the cURL command on a PHP page.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
$request_body = '{"auth": {"tenantName": "xxx", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "admin", "password": "xxx"}}}';
$ch = curl_init('http://xxx:xxx/v2.0/tokens');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_body);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

Question now if I can manipulate the output to display in a better fashion, right now its just a big string, some form of JSON pretty print would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about curl exec (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch); 
print $data;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is returned from the curl_exec command.

Whilst on a different subject, perhaps [Uploading files to Zoho API with PHP Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062636/uploading-files-to-zoho-api-with-php-curl), a question I posted here recently which contains a Curl class example will help you.

In addition, I suggest you read the [manual pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) for the PHP curl methods e.g. the **[curl_exec page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)** - the comments sections often include implementation suggestions.